# Работа с адресной строкой java

Tags: java, браузер

Хотел бы узнать о способах (если таковые вообще есть) работы с адресной строкой браузера с помощью Java, да и вообще взаимодействии последней с браузером. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: по подробнее можно?

Comment: Ты про java-апплеты? Они уже вымерли...

Comment: Или перепутал джаву с джаваскриптом?

Comment: Нет, не Javascript. Разве как-то организовать взаимодействия Java-приложения с другим (в данном случае браузером)?

Comment: Вообще для этого есть библиотека java.net.*;. С её помощю можно запустить браузер на любой странице. Но вопрос следует уточнить!

Comment: 1. Браузер не на джаве. 2. Браузеров много. 3. Вообще ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть дравер selenium для браузеров. 
 Selenium WebDriver – это драйвер браузера, то есть не имеющая пользовательского интерфейса программная библиотека, которая позволяет различным другим программам взаимодействовать с браузером, управлять его поведением, получать от браузера какие-то данные и заставлять браузер выполнять какие-то команды.

WebDriver запускает браузер и позволяет открывать нужные страницы, можно эмулировать нажатия клавиш клавиатуры.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/180217)

Comment: @DmitryMaslennikov с чего это не является?

Comment: при всем уважении к вашему ответу, сейчас он больше напоминает комментарий. попробуйте его написать более развернуто, чтобы не было никаких разночтений. все же не просто так его кто-то добавил в "очередь проверок".